# Problem linking CSS file to HTML file using Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I had some issues linking a CSS file to HTML file while using Django.
Here is my HTML file where I linked a static file name home.css

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'home.css' %}" type="text/css">
```

My folder is organised as so for my templates folder:

```
\Users\me\Desktop\mysite\templates\base\home.html
```

And for my static folder:

```
\Users\me\Desktop\mysite\static\home.css
```

Doesn't someone know from where does the problem come?

Comment: Did you configure your static folder in your settings? Here is the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#static-url)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you set your static folder correct on the settings.

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Comment: Hello Romeo, I had already set up my everything in the `settings.py` file. I would just like to add an information that could maybe help in the futur. In my terminal, it outputs `"GET /static/home.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0` in blue color, so I feel like it does know that there is a CSS file but just cannot execute it.

Comment: Try refreshing your browser's cache by ```Shift + f5``` or ```Control + f5```